# Troposhere to loop EC2 instance creation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I want to create variable number of EC2 instances within my cloudformation template (YAML). 
I am planning to create a stack for EC2 instance creation and loop the same.
I read this is achievable using Troposphere. 
Can someone help me with a template or example?

Comment: While that's also probably achievable using Troposphere, you should also check out AWS CDK (https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).

Comment: @Dunedan can you help me find an example?

Answer (score 0):

Write the below into a class you can reuse for each instance.

https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/examples/EC2InstanceSample.py